# LLamada a un Array en C++

Tags: c++

El programa consiste en almacenar elementos en un array y luego mostrarlos en
pantalla. La funcion de almacenar el array funciona pero luego al llamar al
array en la otra funcion muestra en pantalla numeros negativos y muy largos.

Intuyo que el error esta en:

> tArrayNumero a
>
> const tArrayNumero a

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;

 const int MAX=3;
 typedef int tArrayNumero[MAX];
 void valoresArray();
 void mostrarArray(const tArrayNumero a);

 int main()
 {
     tArrayNumero a;
     valoresArray();
     mostrarArray(a);
     return 0;
 }

void valoresArray()
{
    tArrayNumero a;
    cout << "Introduzca los valores del array";
    for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
}

 void mostrarArray(const tArrayNumero a)
 {
     for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
     {
         cout << a[i];
     }
 }
```

Comment: Estas creando los arrays al estilo de C, en C++ debes usar std::vector

Comment: No creo que el problema este en eso

Comment: Yo no dije que esa la solucion a tu problema, solo te recomende usar tipos de datos adecuados para C++

Comment: Cómo bien dice el compañero, estas creando un Array en el main y otro diferente en la funcion. Prueba a enviar el parámetro a la función reescrita void valoresArray (tArrayNumero int a) , de forma que no devuelva nada y únicamente meta los valores dentro. Espero haberte ayudado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es simple, al principio creas un array y lo llamas "a" y luego llamas a la función valoresArray(), tu problema es que dentro de la función creas otro array con el mismo nombre en vez de recibir el que has creado y darle valores. Esta sería la forma correcta:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAX = 3;
typedef int tArrayNumero[MAX];
void valoresArray(tArrayNumero a);
void mostrarArray(const tArrayNumero a);

int main()
{
    tArrayNumero a;
    valoresArray(a);
    mostrarArray(a);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void valoresArray(tArrayNumero a)
{
    cout << "Introduzca los valores del array" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
}

void mostrarArray(const tArrayNumero a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Espero que te ayude